# Do we allow questions about unofficial game releases (fangames)?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm specifically asking about Pokemon [Ash Grey](http://www.pokecommunity.com/showthread.php?t=180722), which is a fan-made hack of Fire Red/Leaf Green, but this question could relate to any complete game overhaul.

I have a question or two about Ash Grey I'd like to ask but I am not sure whether they are considered on-topic on Arqade, as I'm not 100% sure about it's legality (The only evidence of which I can find is a cursory discussion on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talk:Hack_games#Legal_Issues)):

> **Manga-in-a-bottle -** We really should put up a warning about the legal issues of hacks, if for no reason other than to protect ourselves from being sued
>   **Vekter -** I really don't see any legal issues, aside from the hack carts themselves. Nintendo really doesn't give a damn about hacks or things like that, as long as they're not sold.
>   **Nostalgia -** ...and most hackers go out of their way to prevent their hacks from being sold. The people who sell them are pirates.

Now, I know that discussions of piracy are off-topic, having [made that point clear myself](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7203/whats-bad-in-helping-a-person-who-bought-legal-version-of-a-game-move-their-sav/7205#7205), but what about fan-games such as this?

- Do they fall under the same umbrella as "mods" per se, despite being an entirely new game with little to none of the original content left?
- Or do we avoid such games as their legality cannot be determined?