# How long do close votes remain valid?

Tags: discussion, closing

I've recently asked a question about an unofficial fan-made game, after having [gained clarification](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7338/do-we-allow-questions-about-unofficial-game-releases-fangames) that such questions are in fact [on topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4499/28182).

Some people originally disagreed, and the [question in question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122362/what-pokemon-are-catchable-on-route-1-in-pokemon-ash-grey) now has 3 close votes.

So, my question is: **Are close-votes forever?**

Or do they get removed after a certain timeframe?

Comment: I'm asking a meta question linking to meta-questions about questions. - Quest-ception? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, close votes aren't forever. If the closing threshold of five votes isn't reached in four days ([source 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67585/how-long-does-a-vote-to-close-last), [source 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) the close votes will just harmlessly decay, provided that the question has received more than 100 views.

Comment: Perfect, thanks